# NoSuchMethodException on calling method with reflection

Tags: java, reflection, jira, jira-plugin

I have the following class with a static method, which takes an argument of type `Class<? extends FunctionProvider>` and generates a FunctionDescriptor.

```
public class NoInputFunctionDescriptorFactory {

public static FunctionDescriptor getFunctionDescriptorForClass(Class<? extends FunctionProvider> clazz) {
    FunctionDescriptor functionDescriptor = DescriptorFactory.getFactory().createFunctionDescriptor();
    functionDescriptor.setType("class");
    functionDescriptor.setName(clazz.getSimpleName());
    Map conditionArgs = functionDescriptor.getArgs();
    conditionArgs.put("class.name", clazz.getName());
    return functionDescriptor;
}
```

}

I call this class from a helper method which takes two arguments of type `String`, the factory class name (e.g. `com.example.NoInputFunctionDescriptorFactory`) and the class name of a class, extending `FunctionProvider` (e.g. `com.example.CreateIssuesPostFunction`). These arguments are read from a yaml model, therefore they are of type `String`.

```
 private FunctionDescriptor createFunctionDescriptorFactory(String factoryClassNameString, String functionProviderClassNameString) {
    try {
        Class<? extends FunctionProvider> functionProviderClass = (Class<? extends FunctionProvider>) Class.forName(functionProviderClassNameString);
        Class<?> factoryClass = Class.forName(factoryClassNameString);
        Method method = factoryClass.getMethod("getFunctionDescriptorForClass", FunctionProvider.class);
        return (FunctionDescriptor) method.invoke(null, functionProviderClass);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I call the `createFunctionDescriptorFactory()` method I always end up having a `NoSuchMethodException`:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.NoInputFunctionDescriptorFactory.getFunctionDescriptorForClass(com.opensymphony.workflow.FunctionProvider)`

May someone explain me where I'm wrong?

Comment: You should use `Class<? extends FunctionProvider> functionProviderClass = Class.forName(functionProviderClassNameString).asSubclass(FunctionProvider.class);` insead of performing an checked cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything worked fine when I changed my reflection call to

`Method method = factoryClass.getMethod("getFunctionDescriptorForClass", Class.class);`

using `java.lang.Class`.

Comment: Shouldn't you have passed NoInputFunctionDescriptorFactory.class instead of Class.class?

Comment: Yea, because your method is accepting a Class type argument

Comment: @MubarakaBharucha The method `getMethod()` takes the type of the parameter of the method `getFunctionDescriptorForClass()` as the second argument. So it has to be either `FunctionProvider.class` (which did not work) or `Class.class`.